# Linq query problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query which presents data that is present in CustomersRecord Table as [follows](http://postimage.org/image/ow5xtc78/). Now I'm grouping the data on invoice number and date of transaction and presenting the data in descending order sorted on Date of Transaction. This is the following query I'm using to achieve that.

```
(from result in db.CustomersRecords
                          orderby result.Date_Of_Transaction.Value descending
                          group result
                              by new { result.Invoice_Number, result.Date_Of_Transaction } into intermediateResult
                          select new { InvoiceNumber = intermediateResult.Key.Invoice_Number, DateOfTransaction = intermediateResult.Key.Date_Of_Transaction, TotalAmount = intermediateResult.Sum(result => result.Total_Amount) }).ToList();
```

But mysteriously I'm getting the data in ascending order, the screen shot is shown [here](http://postimage.org/image/owuqvjlw/)

I don't understand what is happening inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the order by to after you do your group by

```
(from result in db.CustomersRecords

                          group result
                              by new { result.Invoice_Number, result.Date_Of_Transaction } into intermediateResult
                          orderby intermediateResult.Key.Date_Of_Transaction descending
                          select new { InvoiceNumber = intermediateResult.Key.Invoice_Number, DateOfTransaction = intermediateResult.Key.Date_Of_Transaction, TotalAmount = intermediateResult.Sum(result => result.Total_Amount) }).ToList();
```

The reason why this is so, is because the group by result.Invoice_Number is overriding the previous order by. Since Invoice numbers are usually given in Date order it appears to be in Date Ascending.

Comment: when i move the orderby as specified i'm not able to get the intermediateResult.Date_Of_Transaction (i mean the intellisense is not helping me with that). Even if i type forcibly " 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,WebStoreWithLinqSql.CustomersRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'Date_Of_Transaction' and no extension method 'Date_Of_Transaction' accepting a first argument of type'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,WebStoreWithLinqSql.CustomersRecord>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?". This is the error i'm getting. Help me out

Comment: @user653622 sorry about that you need to add `Key`. I've updated my answer

Comment: You are a genius (its not at all blarney !!). I was fixated with this problem from afternoon. So its almost 7 hours. I was cleaning the solution, web application, deleted the .dbml classes what not !! Any ways you made my day complete !! Appreciate your immediate feedback. Thank you so much. Have a nice day !!